# Monodroid application not working in real phone

Tags: xamarin.android

I created a Monodroid application, its worked in the emulator with no problem at all. And i copy the .apk file in Andorid phone.

But after installation, it doesnt works.

I am getting Force close issue

**How to install a Monodroid Application in an Android Phone?**

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the full version of Mono for Android or the evaluation? If you're using the evaluation, that doesn't support deploying to a device.

If you're using the full version, are you building in debug or release mode? If you're in debug mode then the shared library is most likely enabled, which means that the APK will not contain everything the app needs to run. You should use MonoDevelop/Visual Studio to deploy to the device, which will install the shared runtime as well as the app.

Comment: can i send this file to some one else who have android sdk and can run it ?